# Automatically generating sub-dir paths in OCTOPRESS menu bar

Tags: content-management-system, jekyll, octopress

I see a similar question already been posted, but was down-voted and left unanswered. Also I was not able to find any answer via google search.

I am trying to use Octopress for both blogging and posting articles. But I don't have much experience with it.

Blog pages work fine and are indexed automatically. However other type of pages (for example *source/projects/project1/project1.md* and *source/articles/article1/article1.md*) are not indexed in archive nor visible on navigation bar. I can still navigate to them automatically by changing the URL, but otherwise they are hidden.

The question: Is there an easy way to automatically generate some kind of a tree for these deeper files? Maybe some kind of a plugin?

Thanks,
KK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely certain how Octopress works, but in Jekyll (which Octopress is based on) you could use the pages accessor to loop through all the pages. It would work something like this:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
    <a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I left the question open for a little longer, hoping more people would tune-in, but it didn't draw much attention. I will happily mark your answer as it leads to the way of accomplishing the task.

Just for completeness I will say that in the end I abandoned Octopress in favor of a perl-based static CMS named "contenticious". Very satisfied with the decision.